# Get form values from route ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form in my ember application, this form has a route with an action on. I want to grab my email and password values and do something with them.

However, I can't grab the values using this.get('email'); which I thought would work. How do I get the values and use them in my action? At the moment it just sets them as empty.

Here is my template.

```
<div class='page-header'>
  <h1>Login</h1>
</div>
{{input
  type='text'
  class='form-control'
  value=email
  placeholder='email'
}}
{{input
  type='password'
  class='form-control'
  value=password
  placeholder='password'
}}
<button
  class='btn btn-default'
  {{action 'login'}}
>
  Login In
</button>
```

Here is my route and action.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    login() {
      const auth = this.get('firebaseApp').auth();
      let email = this.get('email') || '';
      let password = this.get('password') || '';
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("signed in this works");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are the email and password attributes of user model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this.get()` in a `Route`, `this` is the `Route`.  When you use an expression in a template like `{{input value=password}}`, the variable is in the controller.

From the `Route`, you need to access those variables this way:
`this.controller.get('password')`

Hope this helps.